# Аутентификация в ASP.NET MVC и AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, рефакторинг

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла следующая трудность, при передаче данных о пользователе, прошедшем аутентификацию в приложении **ASP.NET MVC** на строну **AngularJS + ASP.NET WebApi**.
В обоих приложениях настроена аутентификация пользователей, хотелось бы, чтобы после авторизации пользователя в **ASP.NET MVC** приложении, пользователь получал доступ (*по средствам: cookies, token или SSO*) к приложению **AngularJS + ASP.NET WebApi**.

Единственный *рабочий* способ к которому я пришел, это создание cookie в приложении MVC (черновой вариант).

ASP.NET MVC:

```
public void CreateCookie(string user, string password, bool isAuth = false)
{
   const string cookiesName = "AUTH_COOKIES";

   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout), isAuth, password, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

   HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie(cookiesName)
   {
      Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket),
      Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout)
   };

   Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
}
```

И считывание данного cookie в AngularJS + ASP.NET WebApi по средствам 'ngCookies' и передача в WebApi

AngularJS + ASP.NET WebApi:

```
public UserInfo GetCookies(string encryptCookie)
{    
    var decryptCookies = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encryptCookie);

    return new UserInfo() { Username = decryptCookies.Name, Password = decryptCookies.UserData };
}
```

Данный способ имеет недостаток в том, что если cookie "жив", то авторизация будет бесконечной, понимаю, что надо ограничить время действия cookie или смотреть на его дату создания.

После изучения различных статей по cookies, token, SSO, запутался в том, какой вариант будет лучшем в данной ситуации?

> Аутентификация в приложении **AngularJS + ASP.NET WebApi** настроена по [данной инструкции](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/?osm=1)

Буду благодарен за любые статьи и ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, для начала стоит разницу между аутентификацией и авторизацией.

Аутентификация - процесс проверки подлинности, т.к. процесс выяснения, кем именно является текущий пользователь.

Авторизация - процесс принятия решения, пускать ли пользователя куда-то.

Вам нужна именно аутентификация. Аутентификация в ASP.NET сводится, по сути, к заполнению `HttpContext.User.Identity`. По сути, со стороны ASP.NET висит несколько разных модулей/middleware, каждый из которых на основании какого-то признака может заявить "о, это юзер такой-то, я подтверждаю!":

#### Старый ASP.NET Forms Auth

[Работает так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx):

1. Вызов `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` или `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` выставляет cookie, в котором лежит зашифрованный username.
2. Глобальный HTTP Module просматривает все запросы и если види куку - аутентифицирует запрос.

Минусы:

1. Подвержен атаке CSRF - любой левый сайт может отрендерить форму, которая сделает POST в ваше приложение, и этот POST пройдет. Для не-апи от этого спасает стандартный механизи Anti Forgery. Для API - не спасает ничего.
2. Не дает сохранить в куку ничего, кроме username. Поэтому вы вынуждены или на каждом запросе вычитывать дополнительные данные для юзера из базы, или вписывать  вместо username что-то свое.
3. Не позволяет отзывать cookies. Нет механизма вылогинивания пользователя раз и навсегда.

#### Cookie Authentication из ASP.NET Core Identity

По сути, исправленная версия Forms Auth. Несмотря на то, что является [частью ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity), [может быть использован и без него](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Работает по тому же принципу, что FormsAuth, но исправляет основную проблему:

Позволяет сохранять в cookie не просто username, а набор claims (утверждений, вида имя: а, роль: б, id пользователя: 5), что позволяет приложению не лезть в базу на каждом запросе и не использовать хитрые схемы сериализации JWT в username.

При этом cookie все равно вечные, неотзывные (валидация "отозвано/не отозвано" лежит на разработчике, через событие `ValidatePrincipal`).

#### OAuth Bearer Tokens

Механизим, позволяющий надежно аутентифицировать пользователя на основе заголовка `Authentication: Bearer`. Предназначен для API и для SPA приложений.

Решает проблемы CSRF и проблему отзыва.

CSRF: Вместо cookie используется http header, который клиентская часть должна сама добавлять в каждый запрос. Нет подставляемой автоматически cookie - нет CSRF.

Отзыв: токены разделяются на два вида:

- access_token - короткоживущий, stateless, используется для аутентификации.
- refresh_token - должгоживущий, обычно statefull, используется для выдачи новых access_token.

Минус - не применим в не-SPA приложении, т.к. браузер сам не шлет соответствующий заголовок.

Процесс подключения:

В качестве основы можно взять стандартный не-core шаблон ASP.NET Web App): Cоответствующий middleware уже будет подключен в самом шаблоне, вызовом `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions)`.

Если у вас отдельная, не SPA страница логина, то со стороны бэкенда - все готово (наиболее вероятный случай)

- Редиректите всех подряд (до логина) на `/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=`
- Пользователю показывает страницу логина
- После логина - его редиректит на `/#access_token=nRUQN1j-wVFoMQ....`
- Берете токен и шлете его в заголовке вида `Authentication: Bearer nRUQN1j-wVFoMQ....`

И выставляете лайфтайм токена таким, чтобы он не заканчивался в течении одной пользовательской сессии (в смысле одного посещения приложения).

По сути вы получаете Cookies Auth для приложения + OAuth для API.

---

Если у вас интегрированная в SPA страница логина - вам придется получать токены ajax-запросом к '/token', предъявляя grant (в вашем случае - password):

- На сервере: переопределяете `ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` так, чтобы он проверял имя и пароль, и пропускал тех, кого нужно.
- На клиенте: отправляете имя и пароль в виде

  ```
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
  ```
- Получаете токен, шлете его в каждом запросе.

---

P.S. Сторонний SSO -по сути сводится к тому, что ваше приложение проверяет аутентификацию/авторизацию пользователя где-то на стороне, и по ее прохождению залогинивает пользователя в самого себя, используя механизи Cookie Auth. Т.е. случай "подключен SSO" с точки зрения работы с Web API сводится к случаю "Cookies Auth для приложения + OAuth для API" выше.

Comment: Вроде я и писал про аутентификацию, но видимо когда начал все формулировать опечатался. Прошу прощения. Спасибо за развернутый ответ.